# Reading excel file from iCloud Drive on Python

Tags: python, excel, path, icloud-drive

i'm trying to read an excel file in my code, whereas it needs the path to the file.

The file path goes iCloud Drive > Documents > Python > 'filename.xlsx'

My current one is:

```
pd.read_excel (r'/Users/matimalik/Downloads/Forsøgsdata.xlsx')
```

But i want to place the files in an appropriate folder - not under downloads.

I have a Macbook btw. I've tried inserting iCloud Drive etc, but none of it worked.

Can somebody help?

Comment: `df.to_excel('/my_new_path/but_not_downloads/test.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED USING THIS CODE!

```
import pandas as pd
from os.path import expanduser as ospath

data =         pd.read_excel(ospath('~/Documents/Python/Kandidatspeciale/TestData.xlsx'),'Ark1')
```